# How to Add Responsive UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to have a custom UIBarButtonItem respond to being tapped by changing the custom UIImage. There does not seem to be an isTapped property so how would one approach checking whether or not the button has been selected?

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selection state can't be inferred from the other dynamic properties, subclass UIBarButtonItem and add a selected flag (or any other state you want to maintain).

An example of subclassing: UIBarButtonItem: https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView/blob/master/RichEditorView/Classes/RichEditorToolbar.swift#L27

Note, if you're only setting the background image or the tint to indicate the button is selected, you'd be able to compare those properties directly to determine the selection state.

Related info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your looking for an `action`. The `UIBarButtonItem initializer` contains an `action` parameter. You use add a `#selector` to add a function to it. The function will do whatever it is you want to get done when the barButton is tapped.

```
// 1. Create a programmatic barButton
var changeImageButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 2. initialize the changeImageButton with a UIBarButtonItem. In the selector is where you can find out if the button was tapped
    changeImageButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Change Image", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(theButtonWasTapped))

    changeImageButton.tintColor = .orange
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = changeImageButton
}

// 3. this will run when the changeImageButton is pressed
@objc func theButtonWasTapped(){

   print("my changeImageButton was tapped")

   // Add the code to change the UIImage here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to track if bar button is tapped or not. UIBarButton itself doesn't have such property like isSelected. But, you can create UIBarButtonItem and set the custom view to UIButton.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let btnCustom = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btnCustom.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
    btnCustom.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedBarButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btnCustom.setImage(UIImage(named:"normalImage"), for: .normal)
    btnCustom.setImage(UIImage(named:"selectedImage"), for: .selected)

    btnCustom.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)

    let barBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnCustom)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtnItem
}

@objc func tappedBarButton(sender: Any) {
    if let btnCustom = sender as? UIButton {
        btnCustom.isSelected = true // or as per your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing. Cheers :)